# Convert non-integer number to day in clojure

Tags: datetime, clojure

I have a function that basically takes in a date string and number of days to add to the given date string

```
(defn add-period [date-string d]
  (t/plus (tf/parse (tf/formatter "yyyy-MM-dd") date-string) (t/days d)))
```

and we call the function thus

```
(add-period "2014-05-12" 7)
;=>  #object[org.joda.time.DateTime 0x2002348 2014-05-19T00:00:00.000Z]


(add-period "2014-05-12" -7)
;=>  #object[org.joda.time.DateTime 0x2002348 2014-05-5T00:00:00.000Z]


(add-period "2014-05-12" 365)
;=>  #object[org.joda.time.DateTime 0x2002348 2015-05-5T00:00:00.000Z]
```

But I also want to do this:

```
(add-period "2014-05-12" 0.5)
```

0.5 will add half a day, and 0.956 will add (57minutes 36 seconds)

I'd appreciate if the function is refactored to accommodate this use cases

I think an issue was raised about this:

[t/days doc misleading or bug?](https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time/issues/192)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use milliseconds.  E.g.:

```
$ lein try clj-time 0.11.0
...
user=> (require '[clj-time.core :as t])
nil
user=> (import 'org.joda.time.DateTimeConstants)
org.joda.time.DateTimeConstants
user=> (t/plus (t/date-time 2015 8 21) (t/millis (* 0.5 (DateTimeConstants/MILLIS_PER_DAY))))
#<DateTime 2015-08-21T12:00:00.000Z>
user=> (t/plus (t/date-time 2015 8 21) (t/millis (* 0.956 (DateTimeConstants/MILLIS_PER_DAY))))
#<DateTime 2015-08-21T22:56:38.400Z>
```

Comment: Thanks, one quick question how can I get the value out, something like `2015-08-21T22:56:38.400Z` and not the whole `#<DateTime 2015-08-21T22:56:38.400Z>`. Thanks

Comment: I tried something like (t/unparse (tf/formatter "yyyy-MM-dd" new-date)) (i.e where new-date is something like `<DateTime 2015-08-21T22:56:38.400Z>`)

Comment: @Jyd your parens are wrong: `(tf/unparse (tf/formatter "yyyy-MM-dd") (t/date-time 2015 1 1))` - the date is the second param to `unparse`